# SQL Only Pull Record with the most recent date

Tags: sql, sql-server

UPDATE: It's now correctly pulling the supplier names for the most recent delivery for each item. The issue I'm having now is that it's not pulling records that don't have previous deliveries (blank dlvry_dt). Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks a bunch for your help so far!

```
;WITH Items As(
Select 
a.bin, a.item, d.item_description As 'Vintage', a.min_reorder, 
c.minor_item_class, c.minor_class_description, a.qty_available, 
a.reorder_threshold As 'Par', a.avg_unit_cost, 
a.qty_available*a.avg_unit_cost As 'Valuation', e.dlvry_dt, g.supplier, 
g.supplier_name,
RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.item ORDER BY dlvry_dt DESC)

from argus.STORE_INVENTORY a, argus.MAJOR_ITEM_CLASS b,
argus.MINOR_ITEM_CLASS c, argus.ITEM_MASTER d, argus.DELIVERY e

inner join argus.delivery_line_item f
on e.delivery = f.delivery
and e.purchase_order = f.purchase_order
and e.customer = f.customer
and e.store = f.store
and e.supplier = f.supplier
full outer join argus.supplier g
on e.supplier = g.supplier


where a.customer = 10005
and a.store = 1
and d.item = a.item
and b.major_item_class = c.major_item_class
and d.minor_item_class = c.minor_item_class
and (b.major_item_class = 15 or b.major_item_class = 17 or b.major_item_class = 14)
and (c.minor_item_class = 830 or c.minor_item_class = 175 or c.minor_item_class = 880 or c.minor_item_class = 661 or c.minor_item_class = 651 or c.minor_item_class = 785 or c.minor_item_class = 716 or c.minor_item_class = 810 or c.minor_item_class = 850 or c.minor_item_class = 885 or c.minor_item_class = 998 or c.minor_item_class = 840 or c.minor_item_class = 855 or c.minor_item_class = 280) 
and f.line_item_status <> 'D'
and e.customer = 10005
and e.store = 1
and f.item = a.item
--and (c.minor_item_class = 176 or c.minor_item_class = 651 or c.minor_item_class = 661 or c.minor_item_class = 716 or c.minor_item_class = 810 or c.minor_item_class = 830 or c.minor_item_class = 840 or c.minor_item_class = 850 or c.minor_item_class = 855 or c.minor_item_class = 885 or c.minor_item_class = 998) 
Group By c.minor_class_description, a.bin, a.item, d.item_description, a.min_reorder, a.qty_available, a.reorder_threshold, a.avg_unit_cost, c.minor_item_class, e.dlvry_dt, g.supplier, g.supplier_name

)
Select bin, item, Vintage, min_reorder, minor_item_class, minor_class_description, qty_available, Par, avg_unit_cost,  Valuation, dlvry_dt, supplier, supplier_name
From Items
Where RowNum =1
Order By minor_class_description
```

Comment: What database platform are you using? MS SQL has the `TOP` operator which would let you grab the topmost record sorted by whatever date value, e.g. `SELECT TOP 1 Value FROM MyTable ORDER BY TheDate DESC`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to use a CTE (Common Table Expression).

With this CTE, you can partition your data by some criteria - i.e. your `Item` - and have SQL Server number all your rows starting at 1 for each of those "partitions", ordered by some criteria.

So try something like this:

```
;WITH Items AS
(
   SELECT 
       Item, Vintage, Qty, DeliveryDate,
       RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY DeliveryDate DESC) 
   FROM 
       dbo.YourTableHere   -- possibly several JOINs
   WHERE
      ......
)
SELECT 
   Item, Vintage, Qty, DeliveryDate
FROM 
   Items
WHERE
   RowNum = 1
```

Here, I am selecting only the "first" entry for each "partition" (i.e. for each `Item`) - ordered by the descending `DeliveryDate`.

Does that approach what you're looking for??

**Update:** if you want to include possible `NULL` entries in `DeliveryDate`, too, you could use something like

```
       RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY ISNULL(DeliveryDate, '99991231' DESC)
```

to turn `NULL` into dates of 31-Dec-9999 - those will always come first when ordered in a descending order.

Comment: This got me so close! Thank you so much! I'm going to edit my original code to show my updated query. The problem I'm having now is that it doesn't show the results that return a blank delivery date, but I want those to show. Any thoughts? Thanks again!

Comment: @fullOfQuestions: so a "blank" delivery date (you probably mean containing `NULL`) should be the "most recent" ?

Comment: Sort of. The goal is to pull up every item in the inventory while also pulling the most recent delivery. If an item is in inventory, but doesn't have a delivery record, it still needs to show, but the part of the page that shows the most recent supplier would be blank. Does that make sense?

Comment: @fullOfQuestions: I'm not sure I totally understand what you're trying to do here.... I tried to formulate an update to my response - maybe that's what you're looking for? If not, you'll have to explain more clearly and in more detail what you're trying to do..

Comment: It got me closer but something funky is still going on. It's a massive query so I probably have something wrong somewhere else, I just don't know how to describe my issue. Thank you SO much for all your help!